# Why do one grid cell is overlapping another grid cell?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am currently trying to complete a challenge where I have encountered this issue-
I have selected certain rows and columns of the grid, but my `subtitle-img` class is still overlapping `subtitle2` class.
Can anyone find the possible reason and solution to this problem?

My code:

```css
body{
    background: #DCE8FF;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    animation: fadein 2s ease-in 0s 1 normal forwards;
}
.main-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 65% 30%;
    column-gap: 5%;
}
.subtitle-content-grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto;
}
.subtitle1{
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: span col2-end;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: span 1; 
}
.subtitle2{
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: span col2-start;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: span 2; 
}
.subtitle-img{
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    height: auto;
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: span col3-end;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: span 4;
}
.sub-img{
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.image-gallery{
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 60%;
}
/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .image-gallery {
      flex: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  }
.image{
    margin-top: 8px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    width: 46%;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
}
.sidebar-content{
    background: #FFE3BF;
}
.post{
    border: 2px solid #FBCA8B;
    margin: 5px;
}
.post>h2,p,a{
    padding-left: 4px;
}
.post>a:hover{
    animation: colorChange 2s ease-out 0s infinite normal;
}
.footer{
    background: linear-gradient(#DCE8FF,steelblue);
    height: 550px;
}
.contact-form{
    margin: 10% 10% 10% 10%;padding: 2% 0 0 0;
    animation: slidein 2s ease-in 0s 1 normal forwards;
}
input[type=text], textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Gray border */
    border-radius: 4px; /* Rounded borders */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Make sure that padding and width stays in place */
    margin-top: 6px; /* Add a top margin */
    margin-bottom: 16px; /* Bottom margin */
    resize: vertical /* Allow the user to vertically resize the textarea (not horizontally) */
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: rgb(39, 132, 247);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: rgb(25, 25, 157);
}
/*Animations*/
@keyframes colorChange{
    0%{
        color: rgba(0, 145, 255, 0.943);
    }
    50%{
        color: rgb(74, 74, 233);
    }
    100%{
        color: steelblue;
    }
}
@keyframes fadein{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes slidein {
    0%{
        -webkit-transform:translateX(-100%);
        -moz-transform:translateX(-100%);
        -o-transform:translateX(-100%);
        -ms-transform:translateX(-100%);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform:translateX(0);
        -moz-transform:translateX(0);
        -o-transform:translateX(0);
        -ms-transform:translateX(0);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="wsc.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Website Styling Challenge</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main-container">
      <div class="main-content">
          <h1>Welcome to this Challenge</h1>
          <p>Here is your list of objectives:</p>
          <ul>
              <li>Lay out the Content & Sidebar</li>
              <li>Create proper margin & spacing around items</li>
              <li>Import & Use A Custom Font</li>
              <li>Color Scheme: Blue & Orange (Use However you see fit)</li>
              <li>Style text appropriately</li>
              <li>change the background color of the sidebar</li>
              <li>Style image grid however you see fit</li>
              <li>Create borders around each sidebar items</li>
              <li>Create grid/flexbox for image and text under "Subtitle"</li>
              <li>Image grow on hover</li>
              <li>Link color change on hover</li>
              <li>Page animation sequence for main items (content, sidebar)</li>
          </ul>
          <p>Do not feel limited by the objective! change or append anything you like. Good Luck!</p>

          <div class="subtitle-area">
              <div class="subtitle-content-grid">
                  <div class="subtitle1">
                      <h2 class="subtitle">Subtitle 1</h2>
                      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, debitis odit. Omnis esse ea aut nisi eos ab, ipsa qui labore sed facilis, quos perspiciatis voluptates aliquid fugiat exercitationem impedit!</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="subtitle2">
                      <h2 class="subtitle">Subtitle 2</h2>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim magni, quam fugit perspiciatis maiores molestias quo totam, saepe obcaecati quia, nulla itaque perferendis culpa suscipit reiciendis reprehenderit! Illum, sapiente earum!</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="subtitle3">
                      <h2 class="subtitle">Topic 1</h2>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, officiis. Illum odio quos, magni quam illo modi rerum maxime et minus dolore autem, nihil veniam. Architecto aspernatur temporibus ipsam dolorem.</p>
                      <ol>
                          <li>Lorem</li>
                          <li>Ipsum</li>
                          <li>Dolor</li>
                          <li>amet consectetur adipisicing elit!</li>
                      </ol>
                  </div>
                  <div class="subtitle-img">
                      <img class="sub-img" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300">
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="image-gallery">
              <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300">
              <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300">
              <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300">
              <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300">
              <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300">
              <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300">
              <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300">
              <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300">
              <img class="image" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-content">
          <div class="post">
              <h2>Post 1</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
              <a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
          </div>
          <div class="post">
              <h2>Post 2</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
              <a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
          </div>
          <div class="post">
              <h2>Post 3</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
              <a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
          </div>
          <div class="post">
              <h2>Post 4</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
              <a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
          </div>
          <div class="post">
              <h2>Post 5</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
              <a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
          </div>
          <div class="post">
              <h2>Post 6</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
              <a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
      <div class="contact-form">
          <form action="/action_page.php">
              <label >First name:</label><br>
              <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="Your First Name"><br>
              <label >Last name:</label><br>
              <input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Your Last Name"><br><br>
              <label for="subject">Subject</label>
              <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `col2-end`, `col2-start`, etc. are template names (set with `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows`) but you haven't set up template names and those names don't exist by default. It looks like unknown template names used with `span` row definitions are treated as "to end of row".

Comment: This change has fixed the issue. `.subtitle1{
    grid-column:1/span 3;
    grid-row: 1/span 1;
}
.subtitle2{
    grid-column: 1/ 2;
    grid-row: 2/ 2;
}

.subtitle3{
    grid-column: 1/ 2;
    grid-row:3/ 3;
}
.subtitle-img{
    grid-column: 3/ 3;
    grid-row: 2/span 4;
}`

Comment: Thanks for the help. But will you please mention when should I use span and when not? Cause I saw a minor difference in the additional amount of area span tag takes. But I want to be sure if it's my mistake or if it actually takes slightly more area.

Comment: `<span>` elements shouldn't take extra space. However the whitespace between them (such as code indents and line breaks) can take up space, though it shouldn't effect your grid layout. Not to be confused with the `span` I mentioned before which is the keyword used with `grid-row` and `grid-column`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this in `.subtitle-img`

```
grid-column-start: 3;
grid-column-end: span 3;
grid-row-start: 2;
grid-row-end: span 4;
```

Comment: It's already resolved, and yes, your solution precisely indicates the mistakes that i made back then.